# Android jvm doesn't support keyFactory generatePublic() ?

Tags: android, key, rsa

Everyone, I recently implemented a RSA encrypt on both PC and Android. Some work well on ***PC (jdk1.6)***, but when I try on Android (***Android 2.1 with jdk1.5***), an error occurs strangely.

The code is like:

```
    BigInteger m = m;
    BigInteger e = e;
    RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    try{
       PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
       return pubKey;
      } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialisation error", e);
      }
    return null;
```

The problem is **PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);** seems to cause a exception, but I can't catch it, even modify it to **Throwable e**. It just jumps to **return null;** but actually the return value is not null, it's an illegal Pubkey with normal exponent(65537) and a bad modulus (be filled with a mount of letter, 'ae3432a***'.

Can anyone test it for me?

Answer (score 0):

We use a RSA-Publickey in a Android 2.3.6 App. We generate the Keys with the following code:

```
// data[] is pre-filled with modulus and publicExponent
String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = "RSA";

BigInteger modulus = (BigInteger) data[0];
BigInteger publicExponent = (BigInteger) data[1];

PublicKey publicKey = getKeyFactory().generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent));
return publicKey;

private static KeyFactory getKeyFactory() {
    if (keyFactory == null) {
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // Algorithm is part of every Android installation. Since we do not get here under realistic
            // circumstances it is OK to crash here.
            throw new HellFrozeOverException();
        }
    }
    return keyFactory;
}
```

If I saw it right, you do the same. Sorry, that I can't help you more...

Comment: Thank you Tobias, I debug these code, I found it may be wrong with the provider, jdk1.5 would use the ___Provider: SunRsaSign___, and android 2.1 use bouncycastle 1.43, But i still couldn't solve it,

Comment: And you say that, you test these code on Android 2.3.6, does it work well?

Comment: Yes we tested this code and it worked well. Due to NFC-Problems we hed to change to Android 4.